# Malicious Windows 7.exe file using all my CPU

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

**My Problem**

I'm a Windows 7 user and to get it out of the way, Windows 7.exe is not a Windows 7 file. It's a smart virus that is using all my CPU.

**What I've Tried**

Every time I hit end process in a task manager, it comes back up and takes all my CPU again within seconds. I thought I could delete the file so I went to file location, but all I found was an empty file called windows 7. This file can't be found on My Computer. I then attempted to stop all services associated with Windows 7.exe, however when I went to services from the taskmanager, none of the current services were highlighted. When I disconnect from the internet, this process isn't able to start up.

**My Question**

I've run out of ideas on how to practically get rid of it and may have to clean install windows. I'm wondering if there is a less bothersome way to do this.

Comment: Well, technically, if you want to delete a file, you can boot an uninfected OS e.g. a live cd, and then that problematic file won't be in use and you can delete it.  Whether or not that helps to any extent, in removing it is another matter. As there may be other malware files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Make sure the virus is not running, aka. unplug your internet.*

***METHOD 0***

Look at the very large, in depth, megathread.

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

***Method one***

Get this file

data-cdn.mbamupdates.com/tools/mbam-rules.exe

Once you have this install malwarebytes on the infected computer, run this file and it will perform a *outdated* manual update.

If mbam finds the virus. GREAT!

if not, you need newer file definitions.

***Method two***

Get a copy of Malwarebytes and run it on a friend's/other computer.

**Grab this file from that computer**

C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\rules.ref

*Note: Starting with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware 1.60, you must also copy the file database.conf located within the Configuration folder which is in the same folder as rules.ref listed above.*

Install mbam on pc, with exe from USB.

Copy those two files on your infected PC.

Run virus scan

I will be willing to help you if these do not work out. Reinstalling windows does not always solve the problem, and if you do decide to do that; I recommend you do a boot scan with Avast afterwards, usually gets those pesky worms.